# Update list from results of comparing two other lists

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists:

```
numbers = [(1,20),(2,20),(3,20),(4,20),(5,20),(6,20),(7,20),(8,20),(9,20),(10,20)]

section1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

number_history = [2,5,9,7,3,8,3,1,7,6]
```

I want to iterate through the number history and check how may of these numbers match the numbers in the `section1` list. Then based on the count of matches update the numbers list to remove the count.

So based on the example data in the lists, the numbers list would be updated to:

```
numbers = [(1,15),(2,15),(3,15),(4,15),(5,15),(6,20),(7,20),(8,20),(9,20),(10,20)]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Try writing some code to do that and let us know what part you get stuck on.

Comment: Maybe `numbers` should be a dictionary or a `Counter`, not a list of tuples, that would probably make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mkrieger1, i will try a dictionary. Think this will work better for what i want to do.